How to interpret hex contained in a string a bytes in Python
Let's say I have a string containing hex value without the hex special char such as:
A = "B8 B9 A5 C1"

How can I convert this variable such as to have a new variable containing the hex value of the string as bytes like this:
B = b'\xB8\xB9\xA5\xC1'


The bytes contains 4 hex values but the str contains two hex values. What do you really want?

I should have put a space between each hex value. What I really want is the 4 hex values the way I formatted it in B.

Ohh that makes more sense. You should edit the OP then.
